# Jquery UI datePicker date range not limited in attached input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This question is very similar to other questions but not exactly - so follow carefully.

I am using a datePicker on a field such as a birthday - I limit the range to past dates only. 
I need to validate the date. the input is not readonly and I dont want it to be.

```
$(element).datepicker({
        dateFormat: dateFormat,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1900:2050",
        maxDate: new Date,
        constrainInput: "true",
        currentText:"Today",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onClose: function (dateText, inst){
            dPickerDate=$('#'+this.id).datepicker("getDate");
            pDate=$.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, dPickerDate);
            if(dateText!=pDate)
                {
                $('#errorFor'+this.id).removeClass("hidden");
                }
            else
                {
                    //do some calculations to save the date... for internal purposes
                                    }

    });
```

the idea is that I check if the date entered was selectable in the date picker - otherwise means it's invalid. Works fine for validation purposes.

Problem is the datePicker allows me to type in a date that is not within the date range. When debugging in fireBug I can see that the value of the datePicker is actually that invalid future date even though it doesn't show up in the datePicker as selected.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you didnt put any input validation. Even though your yearRange is 1900:2050, that doesnt mean the user cannot input other years by typing in the keyboard. I suggest making the datefield readonly so that it can only be access by the datepicker ui, or you can create a function which will check the date which is input by the user.